# New cite command swallows punctuation

Tags: biblatex

I defined a new cite command to show `shorttitle` instead of `author`-`year`combination. The problem is that it swallows the punctuation mark following it.

I tried using `\DeclareCitePunctuationPosition`, but to no avail.

How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeabbr}
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
  \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\textit{\printfield{shorttitle}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
  
\DeclareCitePunctuationPosition{\citeabbr}{r} % doesn't work

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Howlett1975,
  title = {Dictionary of Medieval Latin from British Sources},
  shorttitle = {DMLBS},
  editor = {Howlett, D.R.},
  date = {1975/2013},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  location = {Oxford},
  addendum = {DMLBS},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}    

\begin{document}
  \citeabbr[s.v.]{Howlett1975}; this cite command has swallowed my semicolon.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex` has a very sophisticated system to avoid undesirable double punctuation or punctuation clashes.

In particular `biblatex` will suppress any punctuation after a sentence-ending period (full stop). So '.;' becomes just '.'. The 'problem' is that you would not want to suppress a comma or semicolon after a dot signifying an abbreviation, so 's.v.;' is perfectly fine and need not be reduced to 's.v.'. Since the '.' has essentially two functions, you will have to help `biblatex` along and tell it what you mean when you type `.`. By default `biblatex` assumes a `.` is a period. If you want to enter an abbreviation dot you can say `\adddot` or just `.\isdot`.

Hence, the following displays 's.v.;' just fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeabbr}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[emph]{shorttitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Howlett1975,
  title = {Dictionary of Medieval Latin from British Sources},
  shorttitle = {DMLBS},
  editor = {Howlett, D.R.},
  date = {1975/2013},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  location = {Oxford},
  addendum = {DMLBS},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \citeabbr[s.v.\isdot]{Howlett1975}; this cite command has swallowed my semicolon.
\end{document}
```

[image: DMLBS, s.v.; this cite command has swallowed my semicolon.]

---

If all `.`s that end your postnotes are abbreviation dots, you can automate this by modifying the `postnote` field format (the original definition can be found in `chicago-notes.cbx`)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{% Changed for page compression option
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@comprange}%
    and
    test {\ifpages{#1}}%
  }%
  {\iffieldundef{pagination}%
    {\mkcomprange{#1}}%
    {\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}}%
  {\iffieldundef{pagination}%
    {#1}%
    {\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}%
   \isdot}}%
```

Then you can avoid having to write `\isdot` every time you use `s.v.` in a postnote. But of course that means that a `.` that is supposed to be a sentence-ending period at the end of the postnote will not be recognised as such.

---

If you are using `s.v.` very often you may want to define a handy command for it that avoids the need for `\isdot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeabbr}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[emph]{shorttitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\NewBibliographyString{sv}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  sv = {s\adddot v\adddot},
}
\newcommand*{\sv}{\bibstring{sv}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Howlett1975,
  title = {Dictionary of Medieval Latin from British Sources},
  shorttitle = {DMLBS},
  editor = {Howlett, D.R.},
  date = {1975/2013},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  location = {Oxford},
  addendum = {DMLBS},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
  \citeabbr[\sv]{Howlett1975}; this cite command has swallowed my semicolon.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think I'll use the `\sv` command. Why does it have to call a previously defined bibliography string?

Comment: @NVaughan It doesn't *have to*, but generally in `biblatex` it is preferable to use bibstrings over hard-coded text. (Bibstrings are easier to localise for other languages and generally play better with `biblatex` punctuation handling/tracking. Which probably isn't that important in this case, but becomes very relevant in other settings.)

Comment: Good to know, thanks!